# Can I use WinUSB alongside the built-in HID drivers?

Tags: windows, usb, driver, hid, winusb

I am prototyping a keyboard using a Pi Zero, and I plan to set the Pi Zero up so that it emulates an HID-compliant USB keyboard (for Windows). There are many guides on how to do this, so I do not think this will be an issue. The additional functionality of this keyboard is going to require the ability to configure certain aspects keyboard on the host machine and send those configurations back up to the device.

My understanding is that once I have the pi zero emulating an HID keyboard, I will not have to do any extra work with Windows to get the host to accept the new keyboard device - it will automatically recognize the HID device and use the correct built-in driver. The configuration bit, however, I will have to work on myself. I was planning on writing a Win32 application that calls WinUSB as *the other driver* that handles transfer for the configurations.

On the [MSDN page for selecting a USB driver model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/winusb-considerations), it states that WinUSB is a good option if:

> **Your device is accessed by a single application.**

The question stands thusly:

Does having my device configured as an HID keyboard prohibit me from being able to use WinUSB as a configuration driver? More specifically, does having my keyboard constantly open in an HID filter driver (I believe the HID host is a filter driver) count as the device being used in one application already, where the configuration application would be a second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this answers my question.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9687e8ba-9eb0-4d41-a8ac-973a029e05b2/winusb-sample-to-read-inputs-from-keyboard

> only one driver can be installed on the device, either HID or winusb. you could force winusb onto the keyboard but then it would stop looking like a keyboard to the OS.

Ignoring the irking lack of capitalization in this post, this seems to state pretty conclusively that a separate driver needs to be written. How unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old answer, but it should be possible to create a composite device simply by setting `bDeviceClass`, `bDeviceSubClass`, and `bDeviceProtocol` as specified in the [*USB Interface Association Descriptor Device Class Code and Use Model*](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/iadclasscode_r10.pdf).

The remaining implementation details are found in the *Interface Association Descriptors* ECN included with the [USB 2.0 specification package](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-20-specification). When Windows sees this device class, it should allow a separate driver to be installed for each interface or interface association.

For automatic WinUSB installation, see the [*Microsoft OS 2.0 Descriptors Specification*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/microsoft-os-2-0-descriptors-specification).